# Use 2 columns from PySpark data frame as lookup to replace all other columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set that is a supervisory hierarchy and the first two columns are `id` and `name` and the following columns are `level 1`, `level 2`, `level 3` etc..

In each `level xx` is a number that correlates to the id column.

```
id     name         level 1   level 2   level 3
11     sup org 1    222       333       444
222    sup org 2    11        222       333 
333    sup org 3    11        222       333 
456    sup org 4    222       444       333
```

what i'm looking for is

```
id     name         level 1     level 2     level 3
11     sup org 1    supr org 2  sup org 3   sup org 4
222    sup org 2    sup org 1   sup org 2   sup org 3 
333    sup org 3    sup org 1   sup org 2   sup org 3 
444    sup org 4    sup org 2   sup org 4   sup org 3
```

I've tried to use the `rdd` function but I'm getting an error about the function not be whitelisted?

I've tried the following: where `sup_lookup` is the first two columns of the table above and `sup_org` is the whole table

```
dict1 = [row.asDict() for row in sup_lookup.collect()]

mapping_expr = create_map([x for x in chain(*dict1.items())])


df = sup_org.withColumn('Level1', mapping_expr[sup_org['Level 1']]).withColumn('Level 2', mapping_expr[sup_org['Level2']]).withColumn('Level3', mapping_expr[sup_org['Level 2']])
```

but I get an error about how dict1 list doesn't have attribute .items()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a self join on each level column:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.alias("df") \
    .join(df.alias("lvl1"), F.col("lvl1.id") == F.col("df.`level 1`"), "left") \
    .join(df.alias("lvl2"), F.col("lvl2.id") == F.col("df.`level 2`"), "left") \
    .join(df.alias("lvl3"), F.col("lvl3.id") == F.col("df.`level 3`"), "left") \
    .selectExpr("df.id", "df.name", "lvl1.name as  `level 1`", "lvl2.name as `level 2`", "lvl3.name as `level 3`")

df1.show()
    
#+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
#| id|     name|  level 1|  level 2|  level 3|
#+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
#|222|sup org 2|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|
#|333|sup org 3|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|
#|444|sup org 4|sup org 2|sup org 4|sup org 3|
#| 11|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|sup org 4|
#+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the corresponding names from the id:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
result = spark.sql("""
    select
        id,
        name,
        (select first(df2.name) from df as df2 where df1.`level 1` = df2.id) as `level 1`,
        (select first(df2.name) from df as df2 where df1.`level 2` = df2.id) as `level 2`,
        (select first(df2.name) from df as df2 where df1.`level 3` = df2.id) as `level 3`
    from df as df1
""")

result.show()
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id|     name|  level 1|  level 2|  level 3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 11|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|sup org 4|
|222|sup org 2|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|
|333|sup org 3|sup org 1|sup org 2|sup org 3|
|444|sup org 4|sup org 2|sup org 4|sup org 3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```